# MySQL Join returning multiples, should return single

Tags: mysql, join, union

Hey guys I just noticed that my join statement here

```
        SELECT *
        FROM reports rpt
        JOIN (
            (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
            FROM berries)
            UNION 
            (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
            FROM melons)
            UNION 
            (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
            FROM citrus)
            UNION 
            (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
            FROM table_grapes)
            UNION 
            (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
            FROM tree_fruit)
            UNION 
            (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
            FROM lot)
        ) fruits ON rpt.inspection_number = fruits.report_key
        WHERE rpt.status < '2' 
        ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
```

is returning each row where the query meets the condition, what I was after was trying to
get it to return ONE row, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `limit n` clause to the end to get it to only return one row:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM reports rpt
    JOIN (
        (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
        FROM berries)
        UNION 
        (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
        FROM melons)
        UNION 
        (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
        FROM citrus)
        UNION 
        (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
        FROM table_grapes)
        UNION 
        (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
        FROM tree_fruit)
        UNION 
        (SELECT report_key, shipper, po, commodity, label
        FROM lot)
    ) fruits ON rpt.inspection_number = fruits.report_key
    WHERE rpt.status < '2' 
    ORDER BY rpt.inspection_number DESC
    LIMIT 1                                               -- limit !!
```

This will return the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are returning all rows from reports where status is less than '2' if that row has a inspection_number that matches a report_key from any of the tables berries, melons, citrus, table_grapes, tree_fruit or lot.

What single row did you expect?